# How to fix input not displaying after adding in input checker

Tags: python

Without an input checker, my code works to check for the amount of even/odd numbers when the user inputs in a number. however, as required by my professor I need to add in an input checker, which i'm not sure why but it breaks the code and only works now when entering in a non integer. Also any help on cleaning up the code would be appreciated.

```
def odd_even():
  while True:
    try:
      result = int(input("enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not a number! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return result
       break
  array1 = []
  even = 0
  for i in range(result):
    array1.append(i+1)
    if array1[i] % 2 == 0:
       even = even + 1
    else:
        odd = even + 1
  print ("there are",odd,"odd numbers")
  print ("there are",even,"even numbers")
odd_even()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `return`ing the result when you should just simply break. Also, the `continue` is superfluous because there is no code left to execute in the loop anyway.

```
def odd_even():
  while True:
    try:
      result = int(input("enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not a number! Try again.")
    else:
       break
```

As for the rest of the code, you can use division instead of having to loop:

```
def odd_even():
  while True:
    try:
      result = int(input("enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not a number! Try again.")
    else:
       break
  q, r = divmod(result, 2) # the same as q, r = result // 2, result % 2
  print("There are", q, "even numbers")
  print("There are", q + r, "odd numbers")
```

Example output:

```
>>> odd_even()
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: a
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: b
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: c
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: 10
There are 5 even numbers
There are 5 odd numbers

>>> odd_even()
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: f
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: g
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: h
Not a number! Try again.
enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: 15
There are 7 even numbers
There are 8 odd numbers
```

Comment: @MarkoLudlow No problem. Welcome to SO, by the way! Be sure to mark the answer as accepted with the checkmark on the left once the 15 minute timer is up. That way, others will know that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you added a return statement by mistake which is messing up the flow, Try this.

```
def odd_even():
    while True:
        try:
            result = int(input("enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number! Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    array1 = []
    even = 0
    for i in range(result):
        array1.append(i+1)
        if array1[i] % 2 == 0:
            even = even + 1
        else:
            odd = even + 1
    print ("there are",odd,"odd numbers")
    print ("there are",even,"even numbers")

odd_even()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place your all working codes inside `try` block. I also have did some cleaning up for you.

```
def odd_even():
    try:
        even = 0
        odd = 0

        result = int(input("\nEnter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))

        for i in range(1, result + 1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                even += 1

            else:
                odd += 1

        print("There are", odd, "odd numbers")
        print("There are", even, "even numbers")

    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number! Try again.")
        odd_even()


while True:
    odd_even()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with just removing the return result, and removed the continue as it was not needed.

```
def odd_even():
  while True:
    try:
      result = int(input("enter in a number to find odd and even numbers: "))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
    else:
       break 
  array1 = []
  even = 0
  for i in range(result):
    array1.append(i+1)
    if array1[i] % 2 == 0:
       even = even + 1
    else:
        odd = even + 1
  print ("there are",odd,"odd numbers")
  print ("there are",even,"even numbers")
odd_even()
```